# Python Mange.py syncDB - DatabaseError

Tags: mysql, database, django, django-south

I'm trying to transfer a django project to a new mysql server. I don't care about the data.

I created a new database, changed the name in settings.py, and created a table inside of it to match that of the models.py. when I run python manage.py syncdb I receive an error. Has anyone encountered this error before and if so how do I fix it?

```
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'data_Summertime.livestream_stream' doesn't exist")
```

data_Summertime - Mysql server
livestream - appname
stream - models

Comment: did you convert an existing app to south ? if so, convert it without this column, and then create a new migration which would add `stream` to the app `livestream`

Comment: How do I convert it if syncdb isn't functioning correctly?

Comment: remove the column you are trying to add first. convert to south, and then add the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syncdb creates all tables for you, so drop that table and run syncdb again.